# Wordpress (3.8) Admin UI Style CSS Classes

Tags: css, wordpress

I've been trying to find a list of available style classes that can be used when building a custom module admin page but haven't been successful. Is anyone aware of a codex page or other list that might have these classes and descriptions for things like tables, forms buttons?

Specifically 3.8 would be great but really anything helps as I'm sure most of the classes remain the same.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

That's interesting; after looking around, it seems to be a bit of a mystery.

Several great unofficial online resources:

- [bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style](https://github.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style) is a plugin that "Shows the WordPress admin styles on one page to help you to develop WordPress in a compliant manner."
- [WordPress.org UI Style Guide | A visual reference for the WordPress.org UI](http://dotorgstyleguide.wordpress.com/)
- [Integrating With WordPress' UI: The Basics | Wptuts+](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/integrating-with-wordpress-ui-the-basics/) (long tutorial)

Official resources and other help:

- [Creating Admin Themes « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes)
- For specific quesitons, there is [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I came for [this image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bueltge/WordPress-Admin-Style/master/assets/screenshot-3.png), thanks